# jasmine javascript console.log tests WITHOUT spying on console.log

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to feature test with jasmine. The application console logs a result. I want to test the actual result without spying on console.log 
I am using vanilla javascript and jasmine, nothing else. Is it possible to do this?
Thank you

Comment: spying is probably the easiest way to assert `console.log` is called with expected results. any reason why you cannot use something like sinon?

Comment: why dont you want to spy?

Comment: I guess because it is a feature test so I shouldn't mock anything. Maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Okay, I did it with spying on console.log, thank you